# Server not found after submitting the form

Tags: php, html, forms, server

I've got an annoying problem.
My website https://exmple.com has a contact form.
The logic is placed in the same directory as the send.php file.
In general, an email form works, however, sometimes I get "Server not found" error (1/10). What may be to resign for this weird behaviour?

The form looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="send.php">
 ...
</form>
```

I've already tried:

```
action = "send.php"
action = "/send.php"
action = "https://exmple.com/send.php"
```

Each try gives the same result.

This is a SSL connection, index.php file is in the same directory as send.php.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: change `/send.php` to `send.php` and try.

Comment: server not found means it can't even find your web server host, let alone try to hit the send script on it. And there's no way that the above html snippet would cause this, unless you have a `<base href...>` or wahtever defined elsewhere, or something rewriting/redirecting the form submission.

Comment: what are exact links. of index.php you open and after you submit form? Copy them here (you can change domain if you don't want to show it, but ONLY that.)

Comment: There is a form: https://example.com, and there is a script: https://exmple.com/send.php

Comment: sounds like your hosting company might have issues.

Comment: @cartalot that's the only reasonable explanation.